# Appropriate Exception when instanceof fails

Tags: java, exception

What is appropriate exception when instanceof fail. Something like this:

```
if (user instanceof CustomerModel)
    {
            some logic...
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ClassCastException("Current user is not of type Customer");
    }
}
```

i was going with ClassCastException but i am not 100% sure that it is a good one in this situation.

Comment: If you want `ClassCastException` to be thrown, you can replace your code with `CustomerModel customer = (CustomerModel) user;` and the same exception will be thrown when the type doesn't match. It only makes sense to use instanceof if you want to avoid throwing exceptions, or if you want to throw some other (perhaps custom) exception.

Answer (score 1):

If this is given as a parameter I would use:

[IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument

If this is defined by the state of the application then:

[IllegalStateException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html)

> the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation

Otherwise, I suppose your ClassCastException is ok, but as It was said, then you do not need to create it manually but to cast directly.

Comment: `InvalidParameterException` is part of the security subsystem. I wouldn't recommend using it for non-security-related stuff. (`IllegalArgumentException: Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.`)

Comment: updated, thanks for the hint, I see is the parent of It

Answer (score 1):

Like Eran said, if you just want an 'industry standard' `ClassCastException`, just attempt to cast it and don't use `instanceof`. If you want a custom exception, well, it depends on what you intend. We need more information about what you want in order to give a better example. I'll just give a random example.

For example, if you intend to validate&cast a method parameter or fail with a custom error message, I usually employ this method:

```
public static <T, S extends T> S requireType(Class<S> type, T actual, String varName) {
    requireNonNull(actual, varName);
    if (!type.isInstance(actual))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException('\'' + varName + "' must be of type " +
                                           type.getName() +": " + actual.getClass());
    //noinspection unchecked // It is just checked
    return (S)actual;
}
```

Those scary generic parameters are handled automatically, as in for example:

```
FirmwarePacket castPacket = requireType(FirmwarePacket.class, packet, "packet");
```